# Vue ChartJS get data from a chart in component

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I have a chart in a modal and i want to get the value of the bar when i click on it, to send a request and get more informations.

I saw in documentation https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html
when i click i got the event.

my chart options

```
chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        interaction:{
          mode: 'nearest',
        },
        onClick: this.handleChartClick,
      },
```

the method

```
handleChartClick(e){
      console.log(e);
      
    },
```

But how to reference my own chart like in this other example :

[How to access or get value of specific graph on chart plot by click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219973/how-to-access-or-get-value-of-specific-graph-on-chart-plot-by-click-event)

I'm sure it's obvious but it's my first try with chartJS.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was obvious.

just need a ref attribute in my chart.

```
<Bar v-if="!is_loading"
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="chartData"
    :chart-id="chartId"
    :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
    :plugins="plugins"
    :css-classes="cssClasses"
    :styles="styles"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    ref="myBarChart"
/>
```

and in the method:

```
handleChartClick(e){
   var chart = this.$refs.myBarChart.$data._chart;
}
```